# What causes the error "Operation on non-blocking socket would block" in MSSQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, tcp

ERROR: Exception query was 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX[I1] ON AllAccounts_BAK
(
[Master_received_Day] ASC
)' with exception One or more errors occurred.
ERROR: Exception Inner Exception Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation on non-blocking socket would block.

Here is the Code in C# that executes this query:

```
private void ExecuteQuery(string qStr)
{
    using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qStr, cnx))
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

The connection string is tested just before the query to be sure that it will do a connection by retrieving two rows of data.  No-one else uses the database.  The query has been tested in the SQL Operation Console and it works. It is a tcp connection to an Azure database.  I have loaded data and done queries using this kind of code.  What causes this kind of error?

Comment: Can you update your question to contain a complete repro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,  In addition to connection timeouts, and remote connection timeouts, there is another that I found buried in the bowels of MS documentation.  If in my example, one replaces the two lines doing the open and execution with:

```
  cmd.Connection.Open();
  cmd.CommandTimeout = 0; // 0 sets it so the "command" doesn't time out!
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After adding that line, it works fine!  I'm surprised that this isn't stated more obviously.  If someone could explain this, it would be great!